# Displaying a variable in a Discord bot after adding to its value

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to display a variable "money" for my discord bot.

I add 10 thousand to money (previously defined as 0) and when I do the command "add" it says "added 10K balance. total balance is 10000" (as it should) but after that, whenever I do "bal" (balance) it still displays 0.
Here is my code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        var money = 0
        let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
        let commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if(commandName == "bal"){
          message.channel.send(money)
        }

        if(commandName == "add"){
          money = money + 10000
          message.channel.send("added 10K balance. total balance is " + money)
        }
       }
```

Comment: You can't really change a variable like that, it changes only when the `add` code is runned, for that you may need a database

Answer (score 1):

You will need a database for this. I recommend using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)
It has a great free-plan (No CC Required and Lifetime) is very user-friendly and has good performance.
I recommend you watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_e6E-okvxs).
The Video will guide you through the whole setup.
But for viewing the Database, I recommend using this [Application](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) instead of the Application (Robo3T) shown in the Video, Robo3T crashed a lot for me and doesn't have good reviews in general. If you have any questions, make sure to ask as much as possible! :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).